# At what level is the Asana API rate limit enforced?

Tags: asana

I'm building a suite of tools that integrate with Asana. These tools comprise a web browser extension and a web app (or Chrome packaged app). Do the browser extension and web app share the same API call quota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, API rate limits are enforced per-user. Until we released OAuth support, there was no way to distinguish between different apps (since users were always authorized by the same API key). In future, each app will get its own rate limit quota (per user). If you intend to make them separate apps (and have users authorize them separately) they would then get separate quotas - but if you're either using an API key for both, or sharing one OAuth app, they'll end up sharing their quota, too, even if we roll out the change I mentioned earlier.